# Why is the Custom metric filter for Amazon AWS Logs deleted after 14 days?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I created a custom metric through cloud formation template but it will get deleted after 14 days. How can I retain it for longer time or so that it never expires.

Sample syntax for creating custom metric:

```
"MetricFilter": {
        "Type": "AWS::Logs::MetricFilter",
         "Metadata": {
            "Comment": "Metric Filter for /logGroup/TestInterval logs on specified filter patterns."
        },
        "Properties": {
            "LogGroupName": "/logGroup/TestInterval",
            "FilterPattern": "Error",

            "MetricTransformations": [
                {
                    "MetricValue": "1",
                    "MetricNamespace": "MetricsTest",
                    "MetricName": "ErrorTest"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Amazon CloudWatch retains metrics for 14 days. It is quite possible that your metric did not get deleted -- rather, there was simply no data to display.

Generate some more data and the filter will likely reappear.